# Counterexample to show the set$ \left\{(x_{n})\in l^{p}:{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}x_{n}=0\right\}$ is not closed in $l^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

Let $1\le p < \infty$ and  $G=\left\{(x_{n})\in l^{p}:\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}x_{n}=0\right\}$.

My attempt was to construct a sequence such that its limit exists but it's not in $G$. Using power series I tried to define the following sequence
$$
  x=(x_{n}) 
$$
where $x_{n}=\left(1,-1,\dfrac{1}{4},-\dfrac{1}{4},\cdots,\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},0,0,\cdots\right)$. Clearly, every $x_{n}\in G$. However, its limit is
$$
  x=\left(1,-1,\dfrac{1}{4},-\dfrac{1}{4},\cdots,\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},\cdots\right)
$$
But $x$ is in $G$. Is it possible to fix that counterexample or there exists another counterexample?

Comment: What range of $p$?

Comment: $1\leq p<\infty$

Comment: Are you sure its not $1<p\le \infty$?

Comment: Hi, is this problem coming from some book on functional analysis? If so, could you share the name?

Comment: This was a question from a question set. However, I don't know if my teacher took the problem from a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is true only for $p\in(1,\infty]$. Upper index $n$ will denote the $n$th sequence; lower index $k$ will denote the $k$th term of the sequence. Consider first an auxillary sequence

$$x^n = \left(1,-1,\frac12,\frac{-1}2,\dots,\frac1n,\frac{-1}n,0,0,\dots\right)$$
The termwise and $\ell^p$ limit $$x= \left(1,-1,\frac12,\frac{-1}2,\dots,\frac1n,\frac{-1}n,\dots\right) \in \ell^p,$$
and yes, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k = 0$. But $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k| = \infty$. So there is a bijection $\pi:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ defining a rearrangement $y$ of $x$, by the formula $y_k = x_{\pi(k)}$, such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k = 1 \neq 0.$$
Now define the sequence $y^n$ by $y^n_k=x^n_{\pi(k)}$. Clearly $y^n\in G$ and $y^n \to y\in \ell^p$. The result follows.

For $p=1$, we have boundedness $|\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k | \le \|x\|_{\ell^1}$. So convergence in $\ell^1$ implies convergence of their sums, so necessarily the limit's sum is $0.$

Comment: I like your A but I felt it would be useful to add a  more abstract answer that generalizes to similar Q's.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet there is no need to give me an explanation! I enjoyed your answer as well :)

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude that for p=1 the limit's sum is $0$.

Comment: @SMath A linear functional on a Banach space is bounded iff it is continuous: if $T:X\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded linear functional, then for any $x^n\to x$ in $X$, $T(x^n)\to T(x)$. Concretely $|\sum_1^\infty x_k - 0|=|\sum_1^\infty x_k - \sum_1^\infty x_k^n | \le \sum_1^\infty |x_k - x_k^n| = \|x - x^n\|_{\ell^1} \to 0$

Answer (score 2):

For $p\in (1,\infty].$ Let $C$ be the set of all $x=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ in $l^p$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}x_n$ converges. Then $$ (\bullet)\quad \sup_{0\ne x\in C}|f(x)|/\|x\|=\infty.$$ Let $C_0=\{x\in C: f(x)=0\}.$

Then $C_0$ is dense in $C.$ Proof: If $p\in C$ and $f(p)\ne 0$ then for any $\epsilon \in \Bbb R^+$ there exists $q\in C$ with $\|q\|<\min(\epsilon, |f(p)|)$ and $f(q)=-f(p).$ Then $u=p+q\in C_0$ and $\|p-u\|<\epsilon.$

Therefore $\overline C_0\supseteq C\ne C_0$ so $C_0$ is not closed.

Note: The existence of $q$ follows from $(\bullet)$ since $C$  is a vector space and $f$ is linear on $C.$

Note: $(\bullet)$ is false if $p=1.$

Remark: There is much that has been found about certain real normed linear spaces $B$ with vector subspace $C$ and unbounded linear $f:C\to \Bbb R,$ especially when $C$ is dense in $B$. E.g. when  $B$ is some set of real functions and $f(c)$ is the derivative of $c.$ This is not something I know much of.